# Count duplicates in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

my dataframe looks like this

```
ID      Stage      Recipe
1       ABC        X
1       ABC        D
1       ABC        D
1       ABC        D
2       ABC        X
2       ABC        X     
1       BCD        Y
1       CDE        Y
```

What I want, is to count Recipes that occur more than once in a particular stage (which is equal to a rework) for a particular ID.

So Output for this dataframe should look like:

```
ID     Rework_steps
1      2
2      1
```

Gladly appreciate any help!

Comment: Look into `groupby` and `nunique`

Answer (score 2):

Try using what @RubenHelslott suggests this way:

```
(df.groupby(['ID', 'Recipe'])['Stage'].nunique() == 1).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
ID
1    2
2    1
Name: Stage, dtype: int64
```

Details:

Count the number of unique Stage in each ID and Recipe using `groupby` and `nunique`, then see if that number is equal to 1 which returns a multiindex boolean series. Now, we can use `sum` with parameter `level=0` to sum Trues to the outer most index level 'ID'.

Comment: ok thanks! I would intuitively use: (fab2.groupby(['lotid', 'stage'])['recpid'].nunique() == 1).sum(level=0), which gives me a different result. Since I can have the same recipe in different stages, this would be more appropriate?

Comment: You are grouping by ID and Stage to count the number of recpids for each Lotid and stages, as opposed to groupby by ID and Recipe to count the number of Stages for each ID and recipe.

Comment: I understand what it does, but I don't think it is the solution I was looking for. I don't want to count the unique recipes in every stage, but the duplicates. I don't get how this code can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it myself now, by simplying counting the duplicates
`` duplicates=`df[df.duplicated(subset=['ID','Stage','Recipe'])] ``
and
`duplicates.groupby('ID').size()`

Comment: Glad you got it.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.